# What exactly has been over 200 years?

Tags: the-old-guard

In *The Old Guard (2020)*, Andy and her team had a nightmare about a US marine having her throat slit while taking down a military target:

> Andy: **It's been over 200 years**. Why now?
>
> Genova: Everything happens for a reason, boss.  We have to find her.

What exactly has been over 200 years?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been over 200 years since they've found a new member.

> The previous newest member, Booker, fought and "died" in the Napoleonic wars, early in the 18th century.

Later, Andy reflects that

> Nile gaining immortality and Andy losing hers was meant to make Andy once again appreciate her immortality and what she can do with it.

Comment: In addition, the Why Now was also reflecting Andy's war weariness and frustration and not seeming to make a difference in all the battles she was fighting. I believe she was at the point of wanting to take a break and quit fighting, when they have the dream revealing a new member. Thus her frustration and saying why now?!?